# IdentityServer 4 for Production

Tags: entity-framework, oauth, identityserver4, .net-core

I am looking at samples for IdentityServer 4 for production which doesnt have this annoying InMemory 'this and that'. Basically we need to configure the IdentityServer's IdentityResource, ApiResource, Client, Scope (basically everything) from database.

I have got following (so far) in my code, But not sure how to get all above from the database.

```
    services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<RegistrationContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Any help or pointers are much appriciated.
This is for IdentityServer4, dotnet core, and EF Core.